# I found an oblique asymptote of $f(x) = x\left|\frac{x}{x+1}\right|$, but wolfram didn't. Who is correct?

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f(x) = \frac{x|x|}{|x+1|} =  \frac{x|x|}{|x||1+\frac1x|} =   \frac{x}{|1+\frac1x|}   $

---

### My solution

We are looking for a line $y= \alpha x + \beta$

- $ \alpha = \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{x}{|1+\frac1x|}  \cdot \frac1x = \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{1}{|1+\frac1x|} = 1$

  Hence, $\boxed{ \alpha =1 }$
- $\beta = \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) - \alpha x \stackrel{let \text{ } x\to +\infty}{=} \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x}{1 + \frac1x}  - x =\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x^2}{x+1}  - x \\ \quad=\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x^2-x^2-x}{x+1} = - \lim_{x \to \pm \infty}1-\frac1{x+1} = -1$ 
  Hence, $\boxed{\beta = -1}$

Therefore an oblique asymptote is: $\boxed{y =x-1}$

And it seems I am right:
[image]

---

### Wolfram's solution

- [I seached for f(x) asymptotes and it only found a vertical](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=asymptotes%20x%5Cleft%7C%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bx+1%7D%5Cright%7C) (I did too)
- [Then I asked it explicitly for a horizontal and it found none](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=horizontal%20asymptotes%20x%5Cleft%7C%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bx%2B1%7D%5Cright%7C%20)
- Similar query with the word *oblique* in the comments.

---

That made me really wonder if there is something wrong with my solution. I triple checked everything and it seems fine. Is there something wrong with my solution? Is $y = x-1$ an asymptote?

Comment: You didn't find a *horizontal* asymptote (and anyway there isn't one).

Comment: well, ok oblique asymptote. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=oblique+asymptotes+x%5Cleft%7C%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bx%2B1%7D%5Cright%7C+

Comment: our answer is correct, but you didn't  examine the case $x\to _\infty$. Also, please remove the adjective ‘horizontal’.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha agrees with your calculation of limits ([this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%28x+%7C+x%2F%28x%2B1%29+%7C+%2Fx%29+x-%3E-inf) and [this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%28x+%7C+x%2F%28x%2B1%29+%7C+-+x%29+x-%3Einf), and the same for $x\to - \infty$). I would trust calling a simpler function more than calling a more complex one. Why that particular input doesn't work well, who knows. Maybe it's the absolute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second limit evaluation is a little bit confusing with sign but it seems fine

$$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} x\left|\frac{x}{x+1}\right|-x=\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} x\frac{x}{x+1}-x=\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{x^2-x^2-x}{x+1}=$$

$$=\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{-x}{x+1}=\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{-1}{1+\frac1x}=-1$$

and also your result for the oblique asymptote $y=x-1$ is correct.

Answer (score 2):

As

$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac x{x+1}=1,$$ for large $|x|$ you needn't worry about the absolute value. Then it is clear that $f(x)\sim x$, and

$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\left(x\frac x{x+1}-x\right)=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}-\frac x{x+1}=-1.$$

---

I suspect that Alpha does not find the asymptote because it is computing in the complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a faster way for both sides, with *asymptotic analysis*:

First, we may suppose $x<-1$ or $x>1$ (i.e. $|x>1|$). With this hypothesis, abserve that $\frac x{x+1}>$, so we may remove the absolute value:
$$f(x)=x\,\frac1{1+\frac 1x}=x\biggl(1-\frac1x+\frac1{x^2}+o\Bigl(\frac1{x^2}\Bigr)\biggr)= x-1+\frac1x+o\Bigl(\frac1{x}\Bigr)$$
which proves the line $\:y=x-1\:$ is indeed an asymptote to the curve, and adds that the curve is *above* its asymptote near $+\infty$ and *below* its asymptote near $-\infty$.